# Replace special characters in file with regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to replace part of file that contains special characters and text, but regex not working correctly.

Regexp should work like `(\e&l8D\n)+\f$` in other regex engines:

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(
    "C:\tmp\text.prn",
    [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('cp866')
)
-replace '('+[char]0x001b+'&l8D'+"`n"+')+'+"`f",''
```

Part of file:

```
&l8D│ N18-10│           │30/07      │31/07 16:00│20:30│                           │
&l8DL-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+----------------------------
&l8D
&l8D&l16D(3R(s1p14v0s3b4101T(s3B                               
(s0B(s0S(3R(s0p10.00h12.0v0s0b3T: (s3B(3R(s1p16v0s3b4101T     1.030(s0B(3R(s0p10.00h12.0v0s0b3T - (s3B(3R(s1p16v0s3b4101T     1.063(s0B(3R(s0p10.00h12.0v0s0b3T .(s3B(s0B(s3B
&l8D(s0B
&l8D
&l8D
&l8D
&l8D
&l8D
```

Where `is ESC symbol (ASCII 1B), and last` symbol is FF (ASCII 0C)

Expected result:

```
&l8D│ N18-10│           │30/07      │31/07 16:00│20:30│                           │
&l8DL-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+----------------------------
&l8D
&l8D&l16D(3R(s1p14v0s3b4101T(s3B                               
(s0B(s0S(3R(s0p10.00h12.0v0s0b3T: (s3B(3R(s1p16v0s3b4101T     1.030(s0B(3R(s0p10.00h12.0v0s0b3T - (s3B(3R(s1p16v0s3b4101T     1.063(s0B(3R(s0p10.00h12.0v0s0b3T .(s3B(s0B(s3B
&l8D(s0B
```

Interactive example https://regex101.com/r/15uuEj/1

Comment: In your regex101 example you have the multiline flag set. You have not set that in your powershell.```-replace "(?m)($([char]27)&l8D`n)+`f"'```..... I think that is all you will need

Comment: All the escapes needed are supported by .NET, `-creplace '(?m)(\e&l8D\n)+\f$'` should do

Comment: Sadly, but both are not working correctly...

Comment: Thanks, guys. `'(\e&l8D\r\n)+\f$'` works fine